# Как написать менеджер меню?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, меню

Нужно написать менеджер меню, в котором можно было бы через админ панель создавать меню разного рода (статическое, адаптивное, статическое (не адаптивная верстка) выпадающее меню.... статическое и адаптивное мега меню). Создал верстку всех нужных типов меню, таким образом, чтобы из одного можно было сделать другое меню. (только добавляем или  убираем классы css или обёрточные div). Дальше не знаю, есть только предположения... Вопрос к бывалым, может кто-то решал подобные задачи? Есть похожие скрипты? Что посоветуете почитать (желательно на русском)? Сдаётся мне, что выбрал не верный подход ВООБЩЕ? Я насоздавал кучу css классов, как-то сделал несколько меню. Но наверно есть технологии, что позволяет делать это быстрее? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Не совсем ясно чего вы хотите добиться, какого результата. Вы хотите чтобы в админ-панели можно было создавать некие меню? Для чего эти меню? Это меню какого-то сайта? Что из себя представляют пункты этого меню? Это ссылки на какие-то категории сайта? Есть вложенные категории? Вложенность бесконечная? Опишите как вы представляете управление этим меню из вашей админ панели..

Comment: Приветствую. Видели в Wordpres возможность создания меню? Тоже , но только ещё можно создавать разные типы, в смысле выпадающее, мега и тому подобное. Не знаю точно, может и в WP это есть тоже., но мне нужно для своего сайта, который пишу сам. Вообще менеджер меню -это не так назвал, не знаю, менеджер списков что-ли....  Как пример:.на сайте stackoverflow.com есть графическое меню (вверху справа) и в левой правой части. (главная, вопросы, метки... и просмотр похожих вопросов) Все это можно было бы создавать в одном месте через админ панель, в менеджере... как его не назови....